# Select some of records from database and display in data grid through c# with sqlite database

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I have a sample database like below, and I want to display only the red colored records in the datagrid. I have a condition for how to make those two cells red.

### Sample Database

[image]

For example, I want to display records whose is value less than 10 in the book number column.

I used code like below for making them red.

### Code

```
private void UpdateDataGridViewColor()
{
    if (calledMethod == 2)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            int j = 6;
            DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;

            if (isLate(dataGridView1[j, i].Value.ToString()))
            {
                dataGridView1[j, i].Style = CellStyle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used code something like the following.

### Code

```
private void issueDetails()
{
    calledMethod = 2;
    string connectionPath = @"Data Source=Data\libraryData.dat;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True";

    using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath))
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        connection.Open();
        string query = "SELECT bookno as 'Book No.',studentId as 'Student ID',  title as 'Title', author as 'Author', description as 'Description', issuedDate as 'Issued Date', dueDate as 'Due Date' FROM issuedBooks";
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "issuedBooks");
        int c = ds.Tables["issuedBooks"].Rows.Count;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["issuedBooks"];
        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["Student ID"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        connection.Close();
        this.Totals.Text = "Total Issued Books : " + Convert.ToString(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: for sample i want to display records which is value less than 10 in book no. column

Comment: what's the condition to make them red?

Comment: Are you reading the database cells in any way right now? If yes, then which method are you using?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, `WHERE` Clause in SQL, Linq, copying members from one collection to another via a foreach, filers on dataviews, then there are the different filtering techniques that various ORMS give you, What have you tried so far?

Comment: @0A0D i used code like above for making them red but now i want display only those records those satisfies that condition

Comment: oh ok it is already in the datagrid and you want to query it with values less than 10 in the book no. column, is that correct?

Comment: what is wrong with your sample code?

Comment: @0A0d its working right for my one of forms but in another for i want display only satisfied record in datagrid

Comment: @nEm no i want display them direct from database pragmatically

Comment: That does not make sense to me. What do you mean by satisfied record?

Comment: as shown in sample image i can make them red by condition in one data grid but in another i want display only that 2 records

Comment: then you either create flags for all records you make red, which is the cleaner way to do it or you could check each cell's fore color for red

Comment: #nEm but i want to check condition based on value in database, i dont want to check based on which shown in datagrid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer

```
public void onlyDueReport()
    {
        List<int> array = new List<int>();
        string connectionPath = @"Data Source=Data\libraryData.dat;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True";
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath))
        {
            SQLiteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            connection.Open();
            string query = "SELECT bookno as 'Book No.',studentId as 'Student ID',  title as 'Title', author as 'Author', description as 'Description', issuedDate as 'Issued Date', dueDate as 'Due Date' FROM issuedBooks";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "issuedBooks");
            int c = ds.Tables["issuedBooks"].Rows.Count;
            if (c > 0)
            {
                for (int row = c; row > 0; row--)
                {
                    string date = (string)(ds.Tables["issuedBooks"].Rows[c - row]["Due Date"]);
                    if (isLate(date))
                    {
                        int a = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables["issuedBooks"].Rows[c - row]["Book No."]);
                        array.Add(a);
                    }
                }
            }

            query = "SELECT bookno as 'Book No.',studentId as 'Student ID',  title as 'Title', author as 'Author', description as 'Description', issuedDate as 'Issued Date', dueDate as 'Due Date' FROM issuedBooks WHERE bookno IN (";
            int[] cool = array.ToArray();
            int cou = 0;
            foreach (int a in cool)
            {
                query += a;
                if (cou < cool.Length - 1) { query += ','; }
                cou++;
            }
            query += ")";

            Console.WriteLine(query);
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds1, "issuedBooks");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds1.Tables["issuedBooks"];
            this.Totals.Text = "";
            Report_Viewer.StatusPText = " Total Pending Books :  " + ds1.Tables["issuedBooks"].Rows.Count; 
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
foreach(DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     //check whether bookno. column in 'row' is less than 10
     //and do something
}
```

I just read your comment that you want query from the database directly *before* displaying in datagridview, is that what you want?

For SQLite databases, check out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SQLiteCSharp.aspx), you can use standard SQL select statements to get the records based on your condition. Example `SELECT * From <table> Where bookNum > 10`

That should give you all the records with bookNum greater than 10.

First create your connection,

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionPath)
```

Then the dataadapter

```
 SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
```

Do your table mappings if any.
And then call `da.Fill(ds, "issuedBooks");`

I also noticed you were using `As` in your sql query for the column names. You can actually use tablemappings to map your database column name to the datatable column name. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629944/c-typed-datasets-oledbdataadapter-use-the-column-names-from-the-typed-dataset-a/6650974#6650974).

Comment: no i want code like first i take first any column of row value in database if that value satisfies my condition then i want print in datagrid like that i want check all rows in database

Comment: my main requirement is i want display only past date records from database

Comment: I have updated my answer... you do the same thing as when you fill the dataset but with your column condition query and then bind the dataset to the datagridview